# How to extend Zeppelin Spark interpreter for using custom SparkConf creation logic

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Zeppelin's Spark interpreter creates SparkContext automatically, however, I need to use some custom Scala logic while creating a SparkConf object and load configurations from properties files related to Spark Cassandra connector. How do I extend Zeppelin's built in Spark interpreters to call this custom logic?
I use Scala 2.11 and Spark 1.6 for the project, but I can code in Java for the interpreter also.

Comment: If you want to pass custom properties to SparkConf, then you can set them in interpreter setting page.

Comment: I want to be able to load these using properties files, which are part of my project containing a lot of other pure Scala batch jobs. We already have some utility classes to load these properties according to env, set Cassandra certificates, etc and create SparkConf objects. I was hoping to reuse them.